# how to convert english into arabic dynamically

Tags: php, html, web-applications, web

I have a web in English .. now I want it in arabic. So can any one tell me is there any way to convert whole site into Arabic ... without writting the whole contents in Arabic ???
I want to write dynamically in English and want it to automatically convert if user click on, for example,  arabic version of site button ..
regards

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of appropriate human-readable literary automatic translation. Google Translate does its best, but still, if you don't want your Arabic-speaking visitors to laugh on ugly translation, you'd better translate everything manually and so, create Arabic version ofa whole website. [GNU GetText](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) would be helpful. In case if you still want an automatic translation, you can use [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html)

Comment: google translate lets you store your own manual translations and substitute them, so anything really horrrible or frequently used can be added, giving a better translation.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but nothing will replace an actual, bona fide translation of the content done by a professional, or yourself if you are fluent in both languages.

What you could do as a makeshift solution is this : dynamically append a "dir=rtl" attribute to your html tag (or whatever tag containing text to be translated) and then somehow redirect to a google translated version of that page. But I would personally strongly advise against doing this. The google translation is simply terrible, and you don't want your content to put off your users, or even worse offend them in case of a misfire in the translation...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way in your case is to use Google Translate. Read about it [here](http://translate.google.com/support/)

Answer (score 1):

PHP make developer's life easy, read it in detail [I18N_Arabic](http://www.ar-php.org/I18N/Arabic/Docs/elementindex.html)