# move_uploaded_file function in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem that I'm using `move_uploaded_file()` function to upload files and some of the files named in Arabic so I googled the problem but still no answer I used meta tag and I used Base64 encode and everything but still doesn't work.
What is the solution ?

```
<?php
    $data_name=$_POST['name'];
    $name=base64_encode($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $location="../Files/".$course_name."/";
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
        echo"OK";
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Is it important that the file which is uploaded maintain the same name or can they be renamed?

Comment: no not a problem , but why can't we upload a file name in Arabic ?

Comment: is it showing you any error? i dont think so name can create any error, one solution may b to convert name into english using language library.

Comment: it's doesn't show me any error however the file saved as something like: ط¯ظ„ظٹظ„ ط§ظ„ظ…ظˆط§ط¯ ط§ظ„ط§ط®طھظٹط§ط±ظٹط© ظ…ط­ظ…ظٹ

Comment: _i used meta tag_ What meta tag did you use

Comment: i used the function in PHP utf8-encode , and i have <meta charset="UTF-8"> in my html document

Comment: Have you verified that the path and file that is your destination (`$location.$name`) is actually writable by the web server user?

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be:

Have a database where save your arabic name of file and give that file some custom unique name with current time, also save custom name into db, at time of retreival change file name and show to user.

OR use some name conversion library which convert text from arabic to englidh and vice versa. 
for this purpose have a look on these refferences

[how to convert english into arabic dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660750/how-to-convert-english-into-arabic-dynamically)

[convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers)

OR convert string into utf-8 using php for help:

[PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Do you mean that it's just not possible to manipulate file names with Arabic characters in PHP?

Comment: possible only when server support arabic text